# Notifying applications launcher icon in android

Tags: android

Can we notify the application's Launcher icon with a numerical value in android as I have seen it in the messaging app icon in android when we receive a new message? If yes, How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own widget.

The widget layout should be the same than an application icon, and then you can create a red icon with a number.

I guess that Google did exactly the same with "Reader uncount" widget:

[image]